# AppEngine, DataStore: Preallocating normally-distributed IDs (*not* monotonically incrementing)

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

There are three schemes to set IDs on datastore entities:

1. Provide your own string or `int64` ID.
2. Don't provide them and let AE allocate `int64` IDs for you.
3. Pre-allocate a block of `int64` IDs.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities) has this to say about ID generation:

This (1):

> Cloud Datastore can be configured to generate auto IDs using two
>   different auto id policies:
>
> 1. The default policy generates a random sequence of unused IDs that are approximately uniformly distributed. Each ID can be up to 16
>      decimal digits long.
> 2. The legacy policy creates a sequence of non-consecutive smaller integer IDs.
>
> If you want to display the entity IDs to the user, and/or depend upon
>   their order, the best thing to do is use manual allocation.

and this (2):

> Note: Instead of using key name strings or generating numeric IDs
>   automatically, advanced applications may sometimes wish to assign
>   their own numeric IDs manually to the entities they create. Be aware,
>   however, that there is nothing to prevent Cloud Datastore from
>   assigning one of your manual numeric IDs to another entity. The only
>   way to avoid such conflicts is to have your application obtain a block
>   of IDs with the datastore.AllocateIDs function. Cloud Datastore's
>   automatic ID generator will keep track of IDs that have been allocated
>   with this function and will avoid reusing them for another entity, so
>   you can safely use such IDs without conflict.

and this (3):

> Cloud Datastore generates a random sequence of unused IDs that are
>   approximately uniformly distributed. Each ID can be up to 16 decimal
>   digits long.
>
> System-allocated ID values are guaranteed unique to the entity group.
>   If you copy an entity from one entity group or namespace to another
>   and wish to preserve the ID part of the key, be sure to allocate the
>   ID first to prevent Cloud Datastore from selecting that ID for a
>   future assignment.

I have a particular entity-type that is stored with an ancestor. However, I'd like to have globally-unique IDs and AE's IDs (allocated via *datastore.AllocateIDs* with Go) will not be globally unique when stored under an ancestor (in an entity-group). So, pre-allocation would solve this (they're ancestor-agnostic). However, you are obviously given an interval in response... a continuous range of IDs that have been reserved.

**Isn't there some way to preallocate those nice, opaque, uniformally-distributed IDs?**

While we're on the subject, I had assumed that the opaque IDs from AE were the result of some pseudorandom number generator with a persisted-state for each entity-type, but the word "track" in (2) seems to imply that there is a cost to optimistically generating and buffering IDs that might not be used. It's be great if someone can clarify this.

Comment: Can you rephrase or clarify your question? There's a lot of ancillary information in there and I've found it hard to determine precisely what your looking for?

Comment: Not even if you eliminate everything but the title and the question in bold?

Comment: not really. What are you trying to achieve and why do they need to be globally unique (rather than the current auto id which ensures the whole key is unique, just not the ID by itself)?. Generally GUIDs are used because you don't need to preallocate (and you can't really) - given this - are you really concerned about auto allocated ID collisions? In otherwords - why are you concerned about using your own IDs *AND* auto ids - you probably shouldn't use both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to do the following:

When trying to allocate a new ID for an entity:

Repeat the following:

- Generate a random *K* bit integer. Use it for the entity ID field. *[Use a uniform random distribution]*.
- Create a Cloud Datastore transaction.
- Insert the new entity.  *[If the transaction aborts because the entity already exists try again with a new random number]*.

If you make *K* big enough (for example 128) and have a properly seeded random number generator, then it is statistically impossible to generate an ID collision and you can remove the retry loop.

If you make *K* big enough stop using the integer id field in the entity key and instead use the string one.  Base64 URL encode random number as a string.